# c and c++ shared h file with namespace

Tags: c++, c, header, namespaces

I have a component written in C++ and I want to share an H file between this and a similar component written in C.

In the H file there is

```
namespace X
{
    struct MessageData
    {
     // parameters
    }
};
```

I need both of the components to use same structure - that is why I want to use same file.
How can I make them use same file - because of the namespace?

Solution I found is to wrap the namespace decleration with `#ifdef _cplusplus...`

Is it OK?
Any other ideas?

Comment: Short of removing the namespace entirely, that's all you can do.

Comment: You can also declare the C++ namespace around the location where you include the header file in the C++ project and remove it from the header itself.

Comment: @Daniel Schlößer won't that lead to linker problems?

Comment: Is there really a problem with using '#ifdef _cplusplus', if you do not declare an instance that will be linked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write the header file in C,  that is, without any namespace. Say the header file is `message.h`, then you can use the header file in C++ as:

```
//CPP code
namespace X
{
   #include "message.h"  //put this inside a namespace so that 
                         //you could avoid potential name collision
}

//Use message as
X::MessageData msg; //use fully-qualified name
```

And C code will be this:

```
//C code
#include "message.h"

//Use message as
MessageData msg;
```